Systemd-boot error I want to hide
I'm using systemd-boot as a bootloader and during boot this message shows up:
Failed to acquire RNG data: not ready

Everything works fine, I'd just like to hide it

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64769732/3720510

That's about a completely different program...

what's more, the arch wiki (I'm using arch linux) says "rng-tools is not needed anymore since Kernel 5.6"
